How to merge two json files key values and keep the redundant objects unique
I have two json files with set of common objects {"sample": {"id": "NA12878"}, "wgs_metrics":. I want to merge them together and keep the redundant objects once using python or jq (unique_by). Thanks in advance!
Inputs
File1.json
{
    "biosample": {
        "id": "NA12878"
    },
    "wgs_metrics": {
        "insert_size_std_deviation": "98.2",
        "pct_reads_mapped": "99.63",
        "pct_reads_properly_paired": "97.9",
        "yield_bp_q30": "1996315"
    }
}

File2.json
{
    "biosample": {
        "id": "NA12878"
    },
    "wgs_metrics": {
        "pass_indel_het_hom": 1.49,
        "pass_snp_het_hom": 1.05,
        "pass_snp_ts_tv": 2.13,
        "pass_snps": 8489
    }
}

Expected Output
{
    "biosample": {
        "id": "NA12878"
    },
    "wgs_metrics": {
        "insert_size_std_deviation": "98.2",
        "pct_reads_mapped": "99.63",
        "pct_reads_properly_paired": "97.9",
        "yield_bp_q30": "1996315",
        "pass_indel_het_hom": 1.49,
        "pass_snp_het_hom": 1.05,
        "pass_snp_ts_tv": 2.13,
        "pass_snps": 8489
    }
}

The following code override the file1 removing the redundant objects.
Try1 - Python
with open("variant_counts.json", 'r') as f1:
    data1 = json.load(f1)

with open("NA12878-chr14-AKT1.variant.metrics.json", 'r') as f2:
    data2 = json.load(f2)

#combined_data = data1 + data2
#unique_data = [dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in combined_data}]

merged_data = {**data1, **data2}

with open('mergeed_files.json', "w") as mf:
    json.dump(merged_data, mf, indent=4)
    #json.dump(unique_data, mf, indent=4)
    mf.write("\n")

Try2 - jq
jq 'unique_by([.biosample, .id, .wgs_metrics])' file1.json file2.json

code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json

with open("file1.json", 'r') as f1:
    data1 = json.load(f1)

with open("file2.json", 'r') as f2:
    data2 = json.load(f2)

with open('merge.json', "w") as f:
    json.dump({"biosample": data1["biosample"], "wgs_metrics": {**data1["wgs_metrics"], **data2["wgs_metrics"]}}, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    f.write("\n")

Updated my question here with additional object names aln_metrics and variant_metrics under wgs_metricsin both data1 and data2 json files. variant_metrics :{} in data1 and aln_metrics : {} in data2 inputs are always empty.
I need to merge specifically only the aln_metrics of data1 with only the variant_metrics of data2 instead of the whole wgs_metricsof both data1 and data2 in which the output of data2 written with empty aln_metrics: {} object override the data1 aln_metrics key values with this code.
json.dump({"biosample": data1["biosample"], "wgs_metrics": {**data1["wgs_metrics"], **data2["wgs_metrics"]}}, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

File1.json
{
    "biosample": {
        "id": "NA12878"
    },
    "wgs_qc_metrics": {
        "aln_metrics": {
            "insert_size_std_deviation": "98.2",
            "mad_autosome_coverage": "0",
            "mean_autosome_coverage": "0.00",
            "mean_insert_size": "447.3",
            "pct_autosomes_15x": "0.00",
            "pct_reads_mapped": "99.63",
            "pct_reads_properly_paired": "97.9",
            "yield_bp_q30": "1996315"
        },
        "variant_metrics": {}
    }
}

File2.json
{
    "biosample": {
        "id": "NA12878-chr14-AKT1"
    },
    "wgs_qc_metrics": {
        "aln_metrics": {},
        "variant_metrics": {
            "count_deletions": 848,
            "count_insertions": 850,
            "count_snvs": 8489,
            "ratio_heterozygous_homzygous_indel": 1.49,
            "ratio_heterozygous_homzygous_snv": 1.05,
            "ratio_insertion_deletion": 1.0,
            "ratio_transitions_transversions_snv": 2.13
        }
    }
}

Expected output
{
    "biosample": {
        "id": "NA12878"
    },
    "wgs_qc_metrics": {
        "aln_metrics": {
            "insert_size_std_deviation": "98.2",
            "mad_autosome_coverage": "0",
            "mean_autosome_coverage": "0.00",
            "mean_insert_size": "447.3",
            "pct_autosomes_15x": "0.00",
            "pct_reads_mapped": "99.63",
            "pct_reads_properly_paired": "97.9",
            "yield_bp_q30": "1996315"
        },
        "variant_metrics": {
            "count_deletions": 848,
            "count_insertions": 850,
            "count_snvs": 8489,
            "ratio_heterozygous_homzygous_indel": 1.49,
            "ratio_heterozygous_homzygous_snv": 1.05,
            "ratio_insertion_deletion": 1.0,
            "ratio_transitions_transversions_snv": 2.13
        }
    }
}


json.dumps({"biosample": data1["biosample"], "wgs_metrics": {**data1["wgs_metrics"], **data2["wgs_metrics"]}}, indent=4)

@AndrejKesely I have followup question on additional objects aln_metrics and varaint_metricsof the input files to merge, updated under my original query above. Would it be possible to check? thanks.

The question is closed. I suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow where you describe the problem + post there sample inpupt and expected output, and what have you tried so far.

@AndrejKesely I have opened new question as mentioned, thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78992417/merge-json-files-with-unique-and-selected-objects-only
