merge json files with unique and selected objects only
I have two json files with set of common objects {"sample": {"id": "xxxx"}, "wgs_metrics", "aln_metrics" {}, "variant_metrics" {}. I want to merge them together by the selected objects only and exclude the redundant empty objects. Thanks in advance!
The objects variant_metrics : {} in data1 and aln_metrics : {} in data2 inputs are always empty need to be excluded in the output.
I need to merge specifically only the aln_metrics key value pairs of data1 with only the variant_metrics key value pairs of data2 instead of the whole wgs_metrics of both data1 and data2 in which the output written with data2 empty aln_metrics: {} object override the data1 aln_metrics key value pairs with this code...
json.dump({"biosample": data1["biosample"], "wgs_metrics": {**data1["wgs_metrics"], **data2["wgs_metrics"]}}, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
{
    "biosample": {
        "id": "NA12878-chr14-AKT1"
    },
    "wgs_qc_metrics": {
        "aln_metrics": {},
        "variant_metrics": {
            "count_deletions": 848,
            "count_insertions": 850,
            "count_snvs": 8489,
            "ratio_heterozygous_homzygous_indel": 1.49,
            "ratio_heterozygous_homzygous_snv": 1.05,
            "ratio_insertion_deletion": 1.0,
            "ratio_transitions_transversions_snv": 2.13
        }
    }
}

INPUTS:
File1.json
{
    "biosample": {
        "id": "NA12878"
    },
    "wgs_qc_metrics": {
        "aln_metrics": {
            "insert_size_std_deviation": "98.2",
            "mad_autosome_coverage": "0",
            "mean_autosome_coverage": "0.00",
            "mean_insert_size": "447.3",
            "pct_autosomes_15x": "0.00",
            "pct_reads_mapped": "99.63",
            "pct_reads_properly_paired": "97.9",
            "yield_bp_q30": "1996315"
        },
        "variant_metrics": {}
    }
}
    
File2.json
{
    "biosample": {
        "id": "NA12878-chr14-AKT1"
    },
    "wgs_qc_metrics": {
        "aln_metrics": {},
        "variant_metrics": {
            "count_deletions": 848,
            "count_insertions": 850,
            "count_snvs": 8489,
            "ratio_heterozygous_homzygous_indel": 1.49,
            "ratio_heterozygous_homzygous_snv": 1.05,
            "ratio_insertion_deletion": 1.0,
            "ratio_transitions_transversions_snv": 2.13
        }
    }
}

Expected output
{
    "biosample": {
        "id": "NA12878"
    },
    "wgs_qc_metrics": {
        "aln_metrics": {
            "insert_size_std_deviation": "98.2",
            "mad_autosome_coverage": "0",
            "mean_autosome_coverage": "0.00",
            "mean_insert_size": "447.3",
            "pct_autosomes_15x": "0.00",
            "pct_reads_mapped": "99.63",
            "pct_reads_properly_paired": "97.9",
            "yield_bp_q30": "1996315"
        },
        "variant_metrics": {
            "count_deletions": 848,
            "count_insertions": 850,
            "count_snvs": 8489,
            "ratio_heterozygous_homzygous_indel": 1.49,
            "ratio_heterozygous_homzygous_snv": 1.05,
            "ratio_insertion_deletion": 1.0,
            "ratio_transitions_transversions_snv": 2.13
        }
    }
}

Try1
    def data1(input_aln_metrics):
    aln_input = {}
    with open(input_aln_metrics, 'r') as f1:
        aln_input = json.load(f1)
    return aln_input

def data2(input_variants_metrics):
    variants_input = {}
    with open(input_variants_metrics, 'r') as f2:
        variants_input = json.load(f2)
    return variants_input

def save_output(data1, data2, outfile):
    with open(outfile, "w") as f:
       #json.dump({"biosample": data1["biosample"], "wgs_qc_metrics": {**data1["wgs_qc_metrics"], **data2["wgs_qc_metrics"]}}, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
       #json.dump({"biosample": data1["biosample"], "wgs_qc_metrics": {**data1{"wgs_qc_metrics" : ["aln_metrics"] }}, **data2{"wgs_qc_metrics" : ["varinat_metrics"] }}, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        json.dump({"biosample": data1["biosample"], "wgs_qc_metrics": {**data1["aln_metrics"], **data2["varinat_metrics"]}}, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        f.write("\n")

Updated code:
def data1(input_aln_metrics):
    aln_input = {}
    with open(input_aln_metrics, 'r') as f1:
        aln_input = json.load(f1)
    return aln_input

def data2(input_variants_metrics):
    variants_input = {}
    with open(input_variants_metrics, 'r') as f2:
        variants_input = json.load(f2)
    return variants_input


def save_output(data1, data2, outfile):
    with open(outfile, "w") as f:
        data1['wgs_qc_metrics']['variant_metrics'].update(data2['wgs_qc_metrics']['variant_metrics'])
        #data1['wgs_qc_metrics']['variant_metrics'] = data2['wgs_qc_metrics']['variant_metrics']
        json.dump(data1, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        f.write("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()

    aln = data1(args.input_aln_metrics)
    variants = data2(args.input_variants_metrics)
    save_output(aln, variants, args.output_json)


You will end up doing something like aln_input['wgs_qc_metrics']['variant_metric'].update(variants_input['wgs_qc_metrics']['variant_metric'].

Do I have this right?
json.dump({"biosample": data1["biosample"], aln_input['wgs_qc_metrics']['variant_metric'].update(variants_input['wgs_qc_metrics']['variant_metric'])}, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

No, do it in separate steps.  Do the update, then dump the result.

You are trying to get and set a specific key in a dict. It worked for me when I use the right keys. Do it one step at a time, and just make sure you set the right keys. When you get a key error, that tells you that you have the wrong key. You may be making harder on yourself by trying to do json parsing and assigning multiple dict keys all on one line. It might also be easier without using ** notation where you don't really need it.

aln_input['wgs_qc_metrics']['variant_metrics'] = variants_input['wgs_qc_metrics']['variant_metrics'];        json.dump(aln_input, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4) should work?

It works well, thanks
